# KanBan board that sticks to your desktop

Tags: project-management

I'm looking for a kanban board software that allows me to stick it to the desktop as a single unit and will always popup when I go to my desktop.

If I can sync it with trello or taiga and supports multiple boards, that would be great, but my main need is some persistent widget like board that sticks to my desktop as a whole kanban board.

I tried using sticky note software , but I can't change the background because it comes from AD and they want to keep it standard

Answer (score 2):

Recently I found Kamban http://topols.io/.
Offline & Lightweigt. I like it.

It is not exactly hwo you describe it, but you can give it a try.

Comment: cool, I'll take a look , maybe I can extend it to allow for desktop pinning

Answer (score 0):

The sticky notes aren't really sticky in a sense, its basically an app running on the side with title bar hidden. Not sure, how you want it to be sticky exactly.
By sticky, do you mean without the title bar and is just running in the background?

Also, you could give [Brisqi](https://brisqi.com) a try which is an offline Kanban app, but its not a sticky app as you asked, however it does support multiple boards and groups.